# Gradual increase in I/O usage on website

Tags: wordpress, io

So I've attached the resource usage of my wordpress website over the past 30 days.

You can see the I/O usage has been getting higher and more frequent. I think this is a problem that has caused a massive drop in visits to my site.

I asked my host why this is and he said backs up usually contribute largely to this. Only thing is, I backup once a month not every day.

I've tried optimising my database, disabling plugins but I don't understand why it keeps getting higher.

I have a Analytics plugin that refreshes every hour but I've had that all year and I/O usage only started getting high recently.

The only thing I can think of is Wp Super Cache and CloudFlare not working well together. I've tried different configurations but hasn't helped.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a pretty standard IO log, Over time your db does get a lot bigger and so does your users who end up using a lot of IO. I dont think there is anything to panic right away, but obviously if this is a very huge difference from what you are used to see normally then i think you should look into it seriously. I take caching very seriously and i usually use W3 total cache for this kind of performance optimization. Its a bit tricky in the begining but once you are used to it, it very easy.

**I know you might just want to improve the IO, for which mostly you just need caching but here are somethings that i would do to get the most performance out of a site.**

1) If you are using a VPS or dedicated server install **memcache or something like Redis**, and then configure your plugin according to it. You might have to enable it in your php.ini file but once installed you will see the difference. It will execute the code and give you a save the results in the RAM, on the next request instead of executing the php code it will just hand over the same results. Now it depends on your website, and whether you want to cache it or not. You can setup individual pages to use caching as well.

2) If your plugin has options to **automatically minify and combine html/css/js** files then use it, if not then you should minify and combine them into a single file or as less number of files as possible and then manually upload to your server. It will reduce a lot of time that is spent on requesting a file and waiting for getting the response back. Its usually in milliseconds but if you have a lot of files then it does add up to seconds + unnecessary load on the server.

3)If your plugin has gzip feature, then enable it. It will allow your users to download the **gzipped** css and js files instead of the original large files. This will enormously reduce the number of bits a browser have to download on every attempt.

4) Enable **caching** of files on the browser, your plugin might already have this, but if not then you will have to set some headers which will tell the browser to cache the css and js files in the user browser. So the next time when the user goes to the next page on your website, instead of calling the css/js files from the server it loads them directly from the Cache.

5) Upload your css/js/images files to a **CDN**, that way whenever someone requests a file it will use the shortest route to get your users browser.

6) If your site is not just a personal blog and is making serious money or you just want to please all the huge growing number your users. Then i would suggest you look into auto scaling server platforms, where you set some triggers and the number of servers automatically increase when facing a lot of users / IO and once the number of users go back to normal it automatically scales down. One of the big boys for this sort of service would be **AWS beanstalk**, microsoft azure. Or you can use beanstalkd with digital ocean which is a cheap alternative.

7) Wordpress is quite compatible with **facebook's HHVM** which is an opensource virtual machine designed to use php as just in time (JIT). Php is an interpreted language i.e its written in C/C++ (you can checkout the code at [github](https://github.com/php/php-src)), so when ever you refresh a page, hundred's of line of php code is interpretted by C++ and then compiled and executed. What HHVM does is that it compiles the code and keep it in memory, so when someone else requests the same page it already has a compiled version so it just executes and serves it. So it removes 30-40% of the compiling time from every request, which in turn makes your site 30-40% faster. **Now PHP7 is already out last month and it does have a lot of performance upgrades, so if you are still not sure about HHVM you should definitely try upgrading to PHP7.**

Comment: I'm using WP Super Cache for caching and Cloudflare for it's minifying. It worries me because that's only the past 30 days.

Comment: you should try using this plugin built by godaddy, https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/. It gives you a complete overview of all the memory, load time and number of mysql queries(IO) that every installed plugin on your system uses. Once you get to know which plugins are slowing down your website you can get an alternatives for them or write some according to your needs.

Comment: I run this plugin every now and then. I just did it again and it's no different to the results I got a few months ago when my sales were doing fine.

Comment: Can you share the address of your website, just to understand your problem.

Comment: Ok so what are your main concerns about the website? page loading time or the load on the server ?

Comment: Load on server is perhaps biggest problem. Page load time has been more or less the same for the past 6 months.

Comment: I did a quick check and your website does gets served by cloudflare but i think the css/js files is still being served by your server. Are you sure, you use enqueue to serve the files? I would also recommend you to combine the files togather, and lastly try to reduce the number of queries sent to the database. For eg, site_url(), throughout the website can be saved to a variable or session and can then be replaced by $site_url. So instead of quering the database it will just get the previous value and serve it. There are lots of other functions that can be substituted like that.

Comment: Thanks heaps Omer, I will look at doing those things. I've never heard of enqueing so I'll look into that too. I use to use RocketLoader feature on  Cloudflare which made my site super fast on but that eventually broke the js files on my site. Is there a good resource for database subsititutions  and how to do it that you recommend?

Comment: Well to be honest your website is pretty static so memcache would be a good option to look into. I was having a very similar problem with one of my sites, where the whole server would go down due to lot of querying. But that was due to bad design, so eventually what i did was exported the database from my server and installed it on Amazon RDS. It does become a bit slower this way because wordpress has to request for an external resource, but it removes alot of additional load from the server.